# Extract patch and reconstruct image

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, medical

i am trying my hands on a segmentation task, the images are 3d volumes since i cannot process them at once because of gpu memory constraints, i am extracting patches of the image and performing operations on them.

for extracting the patches i am

```
    def cutup(data, blck, strd):
        sh = np.array(data.shape)
        blck = np.asanyarray(blck)
        strd = np.asanyarray(strd)
        nbl = (sh - blck) // strd + 1
        strides = np.r_[data.strides * strd, data.strides]
        dims = np.r_[nbl, blck]
        data6 = stride_tricks.as_strided(data, strides=strides, shape=dims)
        return data6.reshape(-1, *blck)

    def make_patches(image_folder, mask_folder):
        '''
        Given niigz image and mask files will create numpy files 
        '''
        for image, mask in tqdm.tqdm(zip(os.listdir(image_folder), os.listdir(mask_folder))):
            mask_ = mask
            mask = mask.split('_')
            image = mask[0]
            image_name = mask[0]
            mask_name = mask[0]
            image, mask = read_image_and_seg(os.path.join(image_folder, image), os.path.join(mask_folder,mask_))
            if image.shape[1] > 600:
                image = image[:,:600,:]
            desired_size_w = 896
            desired_size_h = 600
            desired_size_z = 600
            delta_w = desired_size_w - image.shape[0]
            delta_h = desired_size_h - image.shape[1]
            delta_z = desired_size_z - image.shape[2]

            padded_image =np.pad(image, ((0,delta_w), (0,delta_h), (0, delta_z)), 'constant')
            padded_mask  =np.pad(mask, ((0,delta_w), (0,delta_h), (0, delta_z)), 'constant')
            y  = cutup(padded_image, (128,128,128),(128,128,128))#Actually extract more patches by changing stride size
            y_ = cutup(padded_mask,  (128,128,128),(128,128,128))
            print(image_name)
            for index, (im , label) in enumerate(zip(y , y_)):
                if len(np.unique(im)) ==1:
                    continue
                else:
                    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join('../data/patches/images/',image_name.split('.')[0]+str(index))):
                        np.save(os.path.join('../data/patches/images/',image_name.split('.')[0]+str(index)), im)
                        np.save(os.path.join('../data/patches/masks/', image_name.split('.')[0]+str(index)), label)
```

now this will extract non - overlapping patches and give me the patches in numpy array, just as an aside i am converting the image to shape(padding with 0)  896,640,640 so i can extarct all patches

The problem is i dont know if the above code works!to test it wanted to extract the patches and then take those patches and reconstruct the image,now i am not exactly sure how to go about this,

for now this is what i have

```
    def reconstruct_image(folder_path_of_npy_files):
        slice_shape = len(os.listdir(folder_path_of_npy_files))
        recon_image = np.array([])
        for index, file in enumerate(os.listdir(folder_path_of_npy_files)):
            read_image = np.load(os.path.join(folder_path_of_npy_files, file))
            recon_image = np.append(recon_image, read_image)
        return recon_image
```

but this does not work as it makes an array of (x, 128,128,128) and keeps filling up the 0th dimension.

So my question is , how do i reconstruct the image? or is there just a plain better way to extract and reconstruct patches.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If things are reasonably simple (not sliding window) then you could possibly use [skimage.util.shape.view_as_blocks](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-blocks).  For example:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

# Create example
data = np.random.random((200,200,200))

blocks = skimage.util.shape.view_as_blocks(data, (10, 10, 10))

# Do the processing on the blocks here.
processed_blocks = blocks

new_data = np.reshape(process_blocks, (200, 200, 200))
```

But, if you are having memory constraint issues this may not be the best way to go as you are going to be duplicating the original data several times (data, blocks, new_data) etc and you might have to look at doing it a little smarter than my example here.

If you are having memory issues, the other thing you can do, very carefully, is to change the underlying data type of your data. For example, when I was doing MRI data, most original data was integer-ish but Python would represent it as float64.  If you can accept some rounding on the data then you *could* do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

# Create example
data = 200*np.random.random((200,200,200)).astype(np.float16)  # 2 byte float

blocks = skimage.util.shape.view_as_blocks(data, (10, 10, 10))

# Do the processing on the blocks here.

new_data = np.reshape(blocks, (200, 200, 200))
```

This version uses:

```
In [2]: whos
Variable   Type       Data/Info
-------------------------------
blocks     ndarray    20x20x20x10x10x10: 8000000 elems, type `float16`, 16000000 bytes (15.2587890625 Mb)                                                                                              
data       ndarray    200x200x200: 8000000 elems, type `float16`, 16000000 bytes (15.2587890625 Mb)
new_data   ndarray    200x200x200: 8000000 elems, type `float16`, 16000000 bytes (15.2587890625 Mb)
```

vs the first version:

```
In [2]: whos
Variable   Type       Data/Info
-------------------------------
blocks     ndarray    20x20x20x10x10x10: 8000000 elems, type `float64`, 64000000 bytes (61.03515625 Mb)                                                                                                
data       ndarray    200x200x200: 8000000 elems, type `float64`, 64000000 bytes (61.03515625 Mb)
new_data   ndarray    200x200x200: 8000000 elems, type `float64`, 64000000 bytes (61.03515625 Mb)
```

So, doing the `np.float16` saves you about a factor of 4 in RAM.

But, making this type of change puts assumptions on the data and algorithm (possible rounding issues etc).